# Could the Swedish government require a VPN to start logging user activity?

Tags: privacy, subpoena, sweden

This question is basically the same as this question, but for Sweden instead of the United States

[Could the US government force a VPN provider to start logging?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/could-the-us-government-force-a-vpn-provider-to-start-logging)

If the government asked a VPN that was operating in Sweden to start logging user data, would the VPN operator be obligated to do so?

Answer (score 3):

A VPN operator has to follow the laws in the country where they operate. If the laws in Sweden say that a VPN operator must keep logs of user activity, then they have to keep logs of user activity.

If it makes you feel better: There are two kinds of VPN operators. Those that say they log, and those that lie about logging.

Comment: Are VPN operators in Sweden obligated to log user traffic? You didn't answer my question or provide any kind of a reference.

Comment: The Swedish government wouldn't ask a VPN operator to start logging if there was no law that supports the request.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they provide your internet connection, they are at current not legally obligated to keep logs as the Electronic Communications Act only applies to isp:s (SFS 2003:389). However, if they keep logs for their own purposes, they can be compelled to produce them for a criminal investigation.